# Do all exact sequences $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow A \oplus B \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$ split for finitely generated abelian groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, abelian-groups, short-exact-sequences

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated Abelian groups. Are all exact sequences of the form $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow A \oplus B \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$ split?

If not, is there an example?

Comment: What's wrong with the canonical inclusion $B \to A \oplus B$ ?

Comment: It isn't stated what the maps are, so it is not clear that that would give a splitting.

Comment: @Alberto: that $0\to N\to G\to Q\to 0$ splits means that the map $Q\to G$ lifts the projection $G\to Q$. This can fail with the canonical inclusion.

Comment: See Steven Landsburg's answer to the following question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157938/short-exact-sequences-with-no-commutative-diagram-between-them/

Comment: Obviously in the the question homomorphisms are arbitrary, not the canonical ones. The answer is "yes, they're all split" by Landsburg's answer, see the link given by Dag Oskar Madsen.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin your $C$ doesn't split as $A\oplus B$.

Comment: @Fernando: Oops... I wonder what I was thinking.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is true more generally for finitely generated modules over a noetherian ring.  Your question is equivalent to asking whether the sequence 
$$0\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(B,A)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(A\oplus B,A)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(A,A)$$
is surjective on the right.  To prove this, it suffices to localize and then complete at an arbitrary prime $P$, so we can assume we're working over a complete local ring where $P$ is the maximal ideal.  Now it suffices to check surjectivity after modding out an arbitrary power $P^n$, which allows us to assume that all the modules are of finite length.  Surjectivity follows because the lengths  of the left-hand and right-hand modules add up to the length of the module in the middle.

**Edited to add:**  The comments above (which I read after I posted this) remind me that I've posted this same argument before.  If people think this instance should be deleted, I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 6):

I thought it worth adding a reference to this:

Miyata, Takehiko, *Note on direct summands of modules*, J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 7 1967 65–69.

In the paper, the question of the OP is attributed to Matsumura and the solution to Toda.  Then a short argument is given for this case.

The author generalizes this result to the following (which is a quote from MathSciNet):

> "Let $R$ be a commutative, noetherian ring and let $A$ be an
>   $R$-algebra of finite type. Moreover, let $M$ be a finitely generated
>   $A$-module and let $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Using the usual tools of
>   homological algebra and noetherian ring theory, the author establishes
>   the following pair of results.
>
> **Theorem 1:** If $M$ is isomorphic to $N\oplus M/N$, then $N$ is a  direct summand of $M$.
>
> **Theorem 2**: If $0\to N\otimes_R T\to M\otimes_R T$ is exact for all $A$-modules $T$ (i.e., $N$ is pure), then $N$ is a direct summand of
>   $M$."

Comment: Note: I think "$R$-algebra of finite type" means "finitely generated $R$-algebra".

Comment: As does Wikipedia.