# Given a filtration of a finitely generated module over a noetherian ring that "looks" split, is it split?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

The following question came up while trying to determine whether the extension problems in a spectral sequence are trivial.

Given a noetherian ring $R$ and a finitely generated $R$-module $M$ with a filtration $M=F_0 \supset F_1 \supset \ldots \supset F_n \supset F_{n+1}=0$ such that $M \cong \bigoplus_{i=0}^n F_i/F_{i+1}$ (abstractly, but I do not want to assume that this isomorphism is induced by the maps in the filtration), is the filtration split in the sense that all the short exact sequences $0 \to F_{i+1} \to F_i \to F_i/F_{i+1} \to 0$ are split?

I can prove this for $R=\mathbb{Z}$, but my proof does not seem to generalize well. In that case, one can work $p$-locally and then show that a short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ of $p$-groups,

$|\{x \in B|ord(x)\text{ divides }p^k\}|\geq |\{x \in A|ord(x)\text{ divides }p^k\}|\cdot|\{x \in C|ord(x)\text{ divides }p^k\}|$

, with equality iff the sequence is split, and then use that by the assumed isomorphisms, the number of these elements can never strictly increase.

Steven Landsburgs answer in [Do all exact sequences $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow A \oplus B \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$ split for finitely generated abelian groups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167701/do-all-exact-sequences-0-rightarrow-a-rightarrow-a-oplus-b-rightarrow-b-ri) got me hoping that something like this might hold for finitely generated modules over noetherian rings, but a simple induction argument does not seem to work.

Does anyone know if this generalisation is true, and knows a proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take the direct sum of the short exact sequences
$$0\to F_{i+1}\to F_i\to F_i/F_{i+1}\to0$$
for $0\leq i\leq n$.

This has the form 
$$0\to \bigoplus_{i=1}^n F_i\to \bigoplus_{i=0}^n F_i\to F_0\to 0$$
and so splits by the linked answer of Steven Landsburg.

A direct summand of a split short exact sequence is split, so
$$0\to F_{i+1}\to F_i\to F_i/F_{i+1}\to0$$
is split for each $i$.